# Sorting a dataframe column with time stamps

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I am trying to sort and group data of a data frame in python. I have looked at all links online including all the relating StackOverflow. I am really having a hard time. This is how my data looks like. The data was kind of huge so I had put it on a link. Please be advised that the data is has been narrowed down for the sake of this question. Please note that all the data will be from the same day.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OJ0Wr6yjgBNhagsWH9-VMplrvE2WO-ey

So the data is in the format of 2 columns i.e. Timestamp and date.

What I am trying to achieve is that I have a column with all the timestamp sorted and then group all the data that not in order. What I am basically trying to do is split all the different data groups that are not consistent.

I would really appreciate some help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to sort the time and date:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Time_split'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time_split']).dt.time
df.sort_values(by=['Date', 'Time_split'], inplace=True)
print(df)

Time_split       Date
28   00:01:00 2018-05-14
29   00:02:00 2018-05-14
30   00:03:00 2018-05-14
31   00:04:00 2018-05-14
32   00:05:00 2018-05-14
33   00:06:00 2018-05-14
34   00:07:00 2018-05-14
35   00:08:00 2018-05-14
36   00:09:00 2018-05-14
37   00:10:00 2018-05-14
22   20:55:00 2018-05-14
23   20:56:00 2018-05-14
24   20:57:00 2018-05-14
25   20:58:00 2018-05-14
26   20:59:00 2018-05-14
27   21:00:00 2018-05-14
38   21:01:00 2018-05-14
39   21:02:00 2018-05-14
40   21:03:00 2018-05-14
41   21:04:00 2018-05-14
42   21:05:00 2018-05-14
43   21:06:00 2018-05-14
44   21:07:00 2018-05-14
45   21:08:00 2018-05-14
46   21:09:00 2018-05-14
47   21:10:00 2018-05-14
48   21:11:00 2018-05-14
49   21:12:00 2018-05-14
0    22:50:00 2018-05-14
1    22:51:00 2018-05-14
2    22:52:00 2018-05-14
3    22:53:00 2018-05-14
4    22:54:00 2018-05-14
5    22:55:00 2018-05-14
6    22:56:00 2018-05-14
7    22:57:00 2018-05-14
8    22:58:00 2018-05-14
9    22:59:00 2018-05-14
10   23:00:00 2018-05-14
11   23:01:00 2018-05-14
12   23:02:00 2018-05-14
13   23:03:00 2018-05-14
14   23:04:00 2018-05-14
15   23:05:00 2018-05-14
16   23:06:00 2018-05-14
17   23:07:00 2018-05-14
18   23:08:00 2018-05-14
19   23:09:00 2018-05-14
20   23:10:00 2018-05-14
21   00:00:00 2018-05-15
50        NaT        NaT
51        NaT        NaT
52        NaT        NaT
53        NaT        NaT
```

Comment: Do you have a solution on how I could group times that are not in order? These are different times of data. I want to group all rows with incrementing times? Like group all time slots that are in order?